# Could not update Activiti database schema: unknown version from database: '5.20.0.1'

Tags: alfresco, h2, activiti

I am getting a - Could not update Activiti database schema: unknown version from database: '5.20.0.1' ? Any idea why this error occurs ? I am using activiti-engine-5.18.0 jar

I am trying to deploy a process outside of Alfresco Activiti using eclipse.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you are trying to deploy your workflow ?

Comment: RepositoryService repositoryService = activitiRule.getRepositoryService();
repositoryService.createDeployment().addInputStream("myProcess.bpmn20.xml",new FileInputStream(filename)).deploy();
RuntimeService runtimeService = activitiRule.getRuntimeService();
Map<String, Object> variableMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
variableMap.put("name", "abcdefgh");
ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess", variableMap);

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Activiti 5.18 jars on a 5.20 database - what happens if you upgrade to use the same version everywhere?

Comment: How do I perform the upgrade ?? I am using maven to resolve my dependencies. How do I upgrade the jars ? I am using eclipse as my IDE.

Comment: @SunitaNayak Tell Maven to fetch you a newer version? Without the pom file we can't tell you what you've done wrong though

Comment: @Gagravarr...thank you so much. I have updated my pom.xml file. Thanks for the help !!

Answer (score 15):

Check wich version of activiti engine do you use in maven dependencies. Activiti **5.18.0** needs db version **5.18.0.0**. Database version **5.20.0.1** is for Activiti engine **5.19.0.2**.

Check version in your db table **ACT_GE_PROPERTY** and **org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine.VERSION**. They need match.

Comment: Thanks @fersmi !! There was a mismatch in the version of activiti angine and database. I have updated the pom.xml and everything works fine. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: For more details: http://codecramp.com/activiti-setup-eclipse/#Possible_Exception